# Flutter app - Ability to shut down the device

Tags: android, flutter

Is there any way to shut down the device from the Flutter app on Android? I'm talking about the same action that happens when the user shuts down the device by long-pressing the power button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the code below to power off your Android device:

```
Intent requestShutdownIntent = new Intent("com.android.internal.intent.action.REQUEST_SHUTDOWN");
requestShutdownIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.KEY_CONFIRM", false);
requestShutdownIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(requestShutdownIntent);
```

Comment: Sorry. In Flutter, you can use Platform Channel to perform this action in Android, you can read the instruction here: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels

Comment: Thank you. But I am new to App development and I dont know Java or Kotlin. How do I implement this in Flutter?

Comment: @GowthamaanRavi You could go to this article: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels, you will need to know two things: invokeMethod and setMethodCallHandler. In Android, just implement shutdown intent in setMethodCallHandler, and in Flutter, just call invokeMethod when ever you want the app to shut device down

Comment: Yeah, gotcha. Thank you1