# Shut down android device using Flutter application Programmatically

Tags: android, flutter, shutdown

I am making a flutter application for Android TV ( x96 mini) and I need to shut down and turn on this android device from the same flutter application.
How could I implement this

I have tried Platform MethodChannel but couldn't execute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Platform channel should work. Here is the code form this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65094600/14434426):

```
Intent requestShutdownIntent = new Intent("com.android.internal.intent.action.REQUEST_SHUTDOWN");
requestShutdownIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.KEY_CONFIRM", false);
requestShutdownIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(requestShutdownIntent);
```

Comment: where do I need to add this command 
I am getting this error
error: cannot find symbol
                startActivity(requestShutdownIntent);